# Receive ByteString by HTTP Request

Tags: haskell, jpeg, bytestring

I'm trying to download an JPG image with an HTTP request in a way that it can be decoded for further processing.

It looks like a combination of the [HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) and the [stb-image](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stb-image) package should do the trick.

The latter provides a decoding function:

```
decodeImage :: ByteString -> IO (Either String Image)
```

Whereas the ByteString must be strict.

The former promises in their docs, that the 'representation of the bytes flowing' is extrensible via a type class, whereas ByteString and String are already provided by their lib. Here is an example of receiving a String:

```
do
  rsp <- Network.HTTP.simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://url.sth/img.jpg")
  fmap (take 100) (getResponseBody rsp)
```

I could not figure out how to configure the request in order to receive a ByteString. Could someone help me out here?

*Bonus question:* It looks like a Byte String is a good choice for this kind of data. Can someone explain the reason for this? And also, in which way it differs from a ByteArray.

Comment: Any specific reason for using the `http` library instead of other modern ones present ? Note that the package doesn't support https and is mostly in the maintenance phase.

Comment: No there is no reason. Was just a lack of information. Actually I just found out now about the HTTPS, which I'd definitely need. HTTP-Conduit then? Or what would you suggest?

Comment: http-client or http-conduit: [Here](https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client)'s a tutorial for the two.